# Pagamento por credito de celular

Tags: pagamento-online

Bom galera eu sei que existe o Pagseguro o Paypal e outros sites que oferecem forma de pagamento como cartao de credito, boleto e outros. Porém estou a procura de um outro método, porém não fui bem sucedido nas minhas buscas. O que estou procurando na verdade é aqueles meios de pagamentos que aceita credito celular. É  muito utilizado em GameBrowser. Alguém saberia algum pra me indicar

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Cara, eu já usei o PagTotal para compras com crédito de celular...nunca tive problema, o serviço é rápido e sem dor de cabeça. E o suporte deles é bem legalzinho também.

Aqui o site:

http://www.pagtotal.com.br/

Comment: Diz que o serviço foi "Descontinuado"

Comment: Tenta a Card Phone, também já utilizei e era até mais barato do que o PagTotal: http://www.cardphone.com.br/